# How to get Live projects in Front-end Development as a fresher?

Tags: web-frontend

I want to start my career as a front-end developer, though I'm from non-IT background. Where do I get live projects in this field?

Answer (score -1):

Try doing internships where they provide training first then live projects.
If you already know how to work try internships without training.